# Using Nunjucks in flask app - Trying to include HTML

Tags: flask, jinja2, nunjucks

I'm using Nunjucks apart from Jinja2 in my Flask application so I can pass in some variables through JS that I want to render in an HTML template.

-- Here's what I do --

JS controller:

`this.element = DomHelper.htmlToDom( slideTemplate.render({ slide : this.model }));`

{% include "presentation/slide/layouts/layout-1.html/" %}

What I have working:

1. Nunjucks compiles & render works properly without the `{% include..}`
2. `slide` variable is being passed and used fine

Any thoughts or suggestions would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Am I configuring Nunjucks incorrectly? Should I be declaring something in Python code instead?

Answer (score 1):

So I found that I had overlooked a simple thing. My nunjucks was configured to work only for the client side but the `templates` are served through flask. The relative path will only work for the client side data.

***Solution***: I placed the template layouts inside the `static/` directory instead of in server-side `templates/`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you might have a typo. You have:

```
{% include "presentation/slide/layouts/layout-1.html" %}
```

but you say:

> The desired html template I want to includes is in
>   templates/presentations/slide/layouts/ - Here's my folder structure

Is the path templates/*presentations* OR templates/*presentation* ?

Comment: sorry it was a type in my post not the actual code. but thank you